# how to use alert in php and js combined

Tags: php, javascript

have a need to alert through php,
I have the code below. Problem is that it works as long as I dont use header redirect. But   as soon as I use it..I loose alert.

```
echo "I will do some functions here in php";  
if($value == 1){  
alert('ok working');  
}  
header(location: 'someOtherpagethanthis.php');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A redirect instructs the browser to *immediately* fire a brand new request. The response body with the alert will be ignored. You may want to use JS instead to fire a new request after the alert.

```
if ($value == 1) {  
    alert('ok working');  
    window.location = 'someOtherpagethanthis.php';
}
```